# Automating VNC authorization process through command line

Tags: linux, terminal, command-prompt, vnc, vnc-viewer

I am receiving a input as vnc://172.16.41.101&passwd=test

What i want to do with this input is : 
1. Extract the IP address.
2. Extract the password.
3. Launch vncviewer with the ip and password provided.
4. All this should this be automated, once the input is received.

extracting the ip and password is easy.
then i launch the vncviewer with the ip provided, but how do i pass the password to that without prompting the user for the password ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. What application are you writing, who is "I" in "I am receiving an input"? Are you writing a bash script? A native application? Are you just asking for the command line arguments of the vncviewer application? (Which vncviewer, there are lots?) If so, please consult its man page.

Comment: Check this cool `https://github.com/trinitronx/vncpasswd.py` tool out, it can generate an obfuscated password file, that VNC authorization needs.

Answer (score 7):

If your `vncviewer` does not have the `-autopass` option, you can use `vncpasswd` to generate a password file that can be passed into the `-passwd` option:

```
vncviewer -passwd <(vncpasswd -f <<<"password") host:display
```

Comment: For this answer to work, you'll need to install `tigervnc-tools` package to be able to use `vncpasswd`, otherwise you'll not be able to connect with only `vncviewer`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming (by the tags) that you are using the vncviewer program from the command-prompt i think you could do something like this:

```
echo "password" | vncviewer -autopass host:display
```

using your example: vnc://172.16.41.101&passwd=test

```
echo "test" | vncviewer -autopass 172.16.41.101
```

Comment: @Arihant Nahata, did you check this solution? follow-up if it doesn't work somehow or if you have found your own answer please post it :-)

Comment: But there's no `-autopass` switch and that doesn't work.

Comment: If there's no `-autopass`, try the solution using `-passwd` below.

Answer (score 0):

The `-autopass` was unavailable in my version of `vncviewer`.

Neither the tool `vncpasswd` (Apparently comes with `vnc-server`).

---

Demo using `xvfb`, `x11vnc`, run the program `gimp`, if installed, in a virtual X env.

And display with `vncviewer` without prompting for a password.

```
x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 /tmp/vncpass
xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num 30 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -s "-ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24" gimp
x11vnc -rfbport 4544 -rfbauth /tmp/vncpass -display :30 -forever -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth
vncviewer -passwd /tmp/vncpass machine:4544
```

One liner:

```
x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 /tmp/vncpass && xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num 30 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -s "-ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24" gimp & x11vnc -rfbport 4544 -rfbauth /tmp/vncpass -display :30 -forever -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth & vncviewer -passwd /tmp/vncpass $(hostname):4544
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail provided, it's hard to answer this perfectly, e.g. to post the code / commands / configurations to achieve what I'd suggest...  For instance, you'd need to specific exactly which vnc server, client, the platform for each side, etc, etc.

That said, if you can redesign how all of this works - I recommend not using a password at all!

Instead, setup an **SSH Tunnel**, and use **key pair authentication** to secure it.  You can even remove any firewall exceptions for VNC when using this plan!

If you do this, not only will you not have to provide a password, but the entire VNC system will be far more secure!